# How do I download a Facebook messenger audio file?

Tags: macos, audio, facebook

A loved one recorded an audio message on Facebook messenger for me; it looks like the image below. I'm trying to download it, but nearly all of the ways to capture it don't see that the file exists, and the one exception to that downloaded a file that nothing can open.

Can someone please tell me how to download this file such that it can be played? I have 10.9.5, if that makes a difference. Thanks!

[image]

Answer (score 27, accepted):

**UPDATE:** The mobile website solution pointed out by others doesn't seem to work anymore. If you can get it to work, please update this answer again. For now, fallback to one of the methods described below.

**UPDATE:** As pointed out by others, you can open [Facebooks' Official Mobile Messager Webpage](https://m.facebook.com/messages/) and download directly from the interface:

1. Go to https://m.facebook.com/messages/
2. Find the audio file you want to download
3. Click on the dropdown menu on the right of the audio file
4. Press **Download**

---

These generic methods should work for most browsers. You just have to watch out for the fact that different browsers will use slightly different names for the same tools. I will outline the general solution bellow and indicating the exact tool names for Safari, Chrome, and Firefox. *(Feel free to edit this answer to add the names for other browsers!)*

## Method 1 (Network)

1. Go to the chat window that contains the audio file you want to download, using the [Facebook's Messenger Official Website](https://www.messenger.com/).
2. Open the browser's **Web Inspector**

   - **All Browsers** the keyboard shortcut `opt+cmd+I`,
   - **Safari:** `Develop -> Show Web Inspector`,
   - **Chrome:** `View -> Developer -> Developer Tools`,
   - **Firefox:** `Tools -> Web Developer -> Toggle Tools`;
3. Go back to the chat and press the "Play" button of the file you want to download.
4. Find the `Network` tab in the Web Inspector and you will notice that an `audioclip-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx.aac` file has been loaded.
5. Double click on the file and it should automatically download to your default downloads folder (e.g. `~/Downloads`). Alternatively, you should be able to *right-click* on the file and choose the "Download" option.

## Method 2 (Resources)

1. Same as **Method 1**.
2. Same as **Method 1**.
3. Same as **Method 1**.
4. Find the `Resources` (see details bellow) tab in the Web Inspector and find the `audioclip-xxxxxxxxxxxxx-xxxx.aac` file

   - **Safari:**

     - Tab: `Resources`
     - Section: `All Resources`
     - Folder: `Other`
   - **Chrome:**

     - Tab name: `Application`
     - Section: `Frames`
     - Folder name: `Media`
   - **Firefox:**

     - Please add here
5. Same as **Method 1**.

Comment: I was able to use the second method without problems, both on the messenger website and in the message area on Facebook-thanks! I have a question about the first method, though; I don't appear to have a Network tab… is it called something different on Mavericks, or is it hidden someplace non-obvious?

Comment: Try updating `Safari`. Which version are you using?

Comment: I'm using Safari 7.1.6. According to my husband, who built my Hackintosh, I can't get a newer Safari until he updates the operating system, but he doesn't feel like doing that at this time. Do I just not have a Network tab?

Comment: @Goingcrazy maybe under the `Timeline` tab?

Comment: I have a tab called Timelines, and under it there is something called Network Requests… But it, and all the other options, bring up totally empty grids of some sort.

Comment: @Goingcrazy that's is probably because nothing has been loaded / requested yet. Open the network timeline, go back and click on the "play" button. This will send a request to the server for the audio file and should show up in the web inspector.

Comment: I tried it; no luck. All I still have is a blank grid.

Comment: It just blows my mind facebook won't provide an easy normal way to download our OWN FUCKING DATA.

Comment: In Chrome DevTools I found the file on the Network tab. For me, however, the file extension was MP4. Use the filter to filter for "mp4" or "aac" and you should see a resource beginning with "audioclip-xxx..." Right click on it and from the "Copy" submenu select "Copy link address". Paste this in your URL and hit Enter. It should prompt you to download the file. If it is MP4 simply alter the extension to .aac instead and should play just fine.

Comment: The mobile facebook method no longer works, as the link 404s. I haven't tested either of the safari or chrome ones, but firefox doesn't seem to have any way of viewing loaded media.

Comment: Updated the answer accordingly

Comment: On Chrome mobile just activate "Desktop site", then there will be a three dot sub-menu, there'll be a "Download" choice.

Answer (score 11):

In your URL bar instead of typing `www.facebook.com` type in `m.facebook.com`

This will give you the mobile site on your desktop. From there navigate to your messages and you will see downward arrow at the end of the audio clip. Click this and your audio will be downloaded to your default location on your computer, most likely your downloads folder.

Then go back to the normal version of Facebook by replacing `m.` with `www.`

Hope this helps

Comment: The mobile site cannot be loaded in my version of Safari. It DOES load in Firefox, but I don't get any kind of arrow anywhere associated with an audio clip. However, when I clicked on the file name itself, it gave me an option to download it! Thanks! :-)

Comment: this is the best answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work anymore. See my answer above

Comment: Worked for me using Firefox on Mac.  Right-click on play, click 'Save audio as'

Answer (score 3):

Typing m.facebook.com into your Chrome browser should give you a download arrow at the end, but I don't know if it will work for Firefox or Safari.

Hope it helps!

Comment: Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work anymore. See my answer above

Answer (score 2):

Instead of downloading the audio file you can use an audio grabber to record it during playback. I've got good results with [Piezo](https://rogueamoeba.com/piezo/) in the past.

Comment: Then [Audacity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Audacity_(audio_editor)) should work too.